# pyspark foreach with arguments

Tags: python, foreach, pyspark

Reading `pyspark` documentation I know that a foreach is done as:

```
def f(x): print(x)
sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).foreach(f)
```

But, what if I use a function with several arguments?

An example:

```
def f(x,arg1,arg2,arg3): 
    print(x*arg1+arg2+arg3)
```

The point is to use something similar this syntax:

```
sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).foreach(f(arg1=11,arg2=21,arg3=31))
```

Comment: You make a `partial`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make a `partial` function:

```
from functools import partial

sc.parallelize([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).foreach(
    partial(f, arg1=11, arg2=21, arg3=31)
 )
```

`partial` takes as input a function and a sequence of unnamed (`*args`) and named (`**kwargs`) parameters, and produces a *new* function that if you call that function will call the original function `f`, with the unnamed and named parameters already filled in.

Comment: Could you make it more complete ? What does "f" look like ?

Comment: @Itération122442: `f` is the function you want to parallellize that thus in this case has parameters `arg1`, `arg2` and `arg3`, and a positional parameter that will accept items from the list where we perform a parallel mapping.

Comment: how do you assign the values from the iterable (1,2,3,4,5) to one of the parameters of the function?

Comment: @samyi: `.scparallelize([[1,2,3,4,5]])`, or for partial just `partial(f, arg1=[1,2,3,4,5])`